# SimpleHTTPServer on system boot

Tags: python, shell, raspbian, simplehttpserver

I am trying to start the SimpleHTTPServer on system boot. I am using the Raspbian OS which is based on Linux. For this, I have added the following line in *crontab* file:

```
@reboot serverfile.sh
```

Now inside the serverfile.sh, I have put the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

The file execution permissions has been given and it can print an *echo* command when modified. But the server does not start on boot.
The same command,

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

works fine when ran in the terminal.
What am I doing wrong here?

The following is my log for CRON

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Oct 16 07:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[17192]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 16 08:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[17230]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 16 09:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[17265]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 16 10:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[17301]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 16 10:17:03 raspberrypi cron[319]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Oct 16 10:17:03 raspberrypi cron[319]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Oct 16 10:17:03 raspberrypi cron[298]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Oct 16 10:17:03 raspberrypi cron[298]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Oct 16 11:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1718]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 16 11:51:38 raspberrypi cron[276]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Oct 16 11:51:38 raspberrypi cron[276]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Oct 16 12:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1019]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 16 13:17:02 raspberrypi CRON[1051]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 16 14:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1171]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 16 15:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[1283]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Binary file /var/log/syslog matches
```

Comment: have you checked your cron logs?

Comment: No. Let me get back in a moment.

Comment: Use Python's full path: `which python`

Comment: It's python 2.7. But it did work for `python myfile.py` that had some other content

Comment: This post might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root

Comment: @TimLudwinski, Thank you for the link. In fact, I tried with `@reboot myfile.sh`. In that have put `python hello.py` with some basic things for testing. They seem to work fine. So, I think CRON is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using cron, could you use something like an `init.d` script (for older OSes) or `systemd` (for newer OSes).  See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236084/how-do-i-create-a-service-for-a-shell-script-so-i-can-start-and-stop-it-like-a-d.  I'm not sure what Rasbian uses to start services; maybe something different from either of those.  I think reboot scripts would generally used to clean up resources upon boot, rather than to run services.

Comment: If the server starts on boot, that's all I need. Let me check with your suggestions